# Java application sometimes hangs at start

Tags: java, process, freeze

It's a really weird issue:
Sometimes when I try to start my app, the process creates himself but doesn't do anything.
And sometimes it starts.

I tried to look on the web but I didn't find anything helpful for now. So I was wondering if any of you had the same problem and how did you solved it.

PS:I tried to see the console and show printStackTrace but, there wasn't anything. Just the regulars logs until it hangs (before showing any GUI).

Edit:

[Here is the cmd with java -jar when it happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3di3.png)

[And Task manager stuck at 30 000k memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyBux.png)

My program is just calling : read("MaxAttempts")

```
    public String read(String NomFonction) {
    String ConfigFile = cfgfile.getPath();
    try{
        InputStream flux=new FileInputStream(ConfigFile); 
        InputStreamReader lecture=new InputStreamReader(flux);
        BufferedReader buff=new BufferedReader(lecture);
        String ligne;
        String Fonction = null;
        while ((ligne=buff.readLine())!=null){
            if(ligne.contains(NomFonction + "=")) {
                Fonction = ligne.split("=")[1];
            }
        }
        buff.close();
        if(!Fonction.equals(null)) {
            return Fonction;
        }
        } catch(Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "Error";
}
```

Comment: Could not reproduce.

Comment: That is very bad and we all are sorry for that. But we can try and help if you can post your code and any error that you are getting.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I edited the post and added some infos.
But there isn't many things :/

Comment: @RapidEv What is there in the ConfigFile?

Comment: Just this at different lines:
Language=en_US
MaxAttempt=3
Console=true

Comment: Just a little hint:  Don't ever write `<something>.equals(null)"  This will crash (NPE) if something is null.  You should write: "if (Fonction != null)" ...

Comment: @JohnTangBoyland Oh thanks, I didn't know :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reproduce it in the debug mode.

Keep starting the process in the debug mode until it is reproduced. When the program hangs, see the list of your threads. If the configuration reading happens in the main thread (and it looks so. If not, pick up the required thread), depending on your IDE, right click on the tread and select "suspend" (then again, depending on your IDE).

It will show where your thread hung.

Comment: I actually never used the debug mode in eclipse :/

Comment: You should then. It will save a lot of your precious time in the future.

Comment: I'll try it x) Thanks